# python pandas groupby by multi columns problem on sum() and total add up

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a data of 90k rows and 14 columns.
want to add up the duplicated rows(13columns), except the column "quantity".

**Sorry that i can not put the original data here for your easy check.
all below codes are pseudo codes, so ignore the obvious clerical error**

- **problem 1:**

when i use

```
# gp_cols is the list of 13 columns name.
# except "quantity" column is uint32, other columns converted to category.

gp_cols = ['dddd-mm', 'province', 'city', 'maker', 'brand', 'model', \
           'model-year',  'color', 'liters', 'fueltype','type', 'appType', 'domesticimported']
    
gp = df_test.groupby(by=gp_cols, as_index=True)

# when i do gp.sum() or gp['quantity'].sum() or  gp.size(), the memory error will come up:
# even i just pull out the first 10k rows, same error happend.
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 455. PiB for an array with shape (512584853784231936,) and data type int8
```

why and how to avoid this?

- **problem 2:**

when i use cumsum() to solve the above problem, the final answer seems correct.
But when i compare the total value of 'quantity' and 'cumQty', they are not same.

```
df_test.sort_values(by=gp_cols,ignore_index=True, inplace=True)

t5 = df_test.join(gp.cumsum().rename(columns={'quantity':'cumQty'}))
t6 = t5.drop_duplicates(subset=gp_cols, keep='last')

print(t6['cumQty'].sum() )
print(t5['quantity'].sum())
print(df_test['quantity'].sum())
print(t5.shape,t6.shape)

# result after drop_duplicates are incorrect.
# t5 size is same to original data, t6 is the length of grouper. 633576 rows
#below 5001rows sample data result: drop_duplicates leads to data lost.
#37013
#39617
#39617
# (5001, 16) (2642, 16)

# run twice
#37199
#39617
#39617
#(5001, 15) (2642, 15)

# run third
#39860
#39617
#39617
#(5001, 15) (2642, 15)

# run forth
#58515
#39617
#39617
#(5001, 15) (2642, 15)


# then i tried join the 13 columns into one new reference column "key", the groupby result is correct.
t7 = df_test.iloc[:,0].astype('str')
for i in range(1, len(gp_cols)):
    t7 = t7 + "_" + df_test[gp_cols[i]].astype('str')

df_test['key'] = t7

gp7 = df_test.groupby(by="key", as_index=False)

print(gp7.sum()['quantity'].sum())
print(gp7.size())

# the quantity now is correct, same to original one's sum.  
# below is the 5001 sample rows result. no data lost by reference column created.
# 39617
# 2642 rows x 2 columns
```

Why after drop duplicates, the total quantity is changed.
I guess when drop duplicates, some cumsum rows are dropped. or the problem is from join?

How can i get the correct answer, without create reference column and split the reference column?

Thanks!

Best Regards,
Kevin

for problem 1, as Joran's recommendation, i pull out a 4999 rows data for check both problem 1 and problem 2.
The link may expired after some time.

Even you only pull the first 1000rows, the codes will lead to problem 1, but no problem 2 found.

[5001 rows sample data, has problem1 and problem2](https://drive.weixin.qq.com/s?k=ANoAygdRAA8LAjG8bDAEQAogZ4AJo)

Comment: i also check the t5 create line. `len(   gp.cumsum().rename(columns={'quantity':'cumQty’})  )` is  905069. so the join may has no problem. highly suspected line is drop_duplicates

Comment: you are doing something strange no way 90k rows x 14 cols is 415 peta bytes ... if you actually want help please provide a sample data set (It can be totally fake but must demonstrate the issue)

Comment: thanks for your comment on problem 1! let me check how to upload a pkl file.  I just checked. Even  just select 1000rows, the same error happens.

Comment: For problem2, i am not sure if anyone ever meet the similar problem. or there are other alternative easier way to reach the target instead of using the way, i tried.

Comment: I have completed the tast by reference columns, then linked back to original data frame.
ori has 21,662,305  vehicles and final col has 21,662,305 vehicles
Wall time: 5min 46s